# How to get path of my project location when running JAVA class via DWR

Tags: java, file, tomcat, dwr

I need to access file inside my web project in a java file, when java class was called via DWR.

I am using Apache tomcat as web server with eclipse ide. I am not able to set proper path to access the file in fact default path is set as my elipse installation folder.

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

when above code run via DWR, it shows my Eclipse installation fodler.

I have file to read directly below my project location.

Can some please help me how to get path of my project location when running JAVA class via DWR.

Note : Java class is not a servlet.

Comment: any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Can some JAVA expert please help me.